# How can I get short[] from a ByteBuffer

Tags: android, bytebuffer

I am using JNI code in an Android project in which the JNI native function requires a short[] argument. However, the original data is stored as a ByteBuffer. I'm trying the convert the data format as follows.

```
ByteBuffer rgbBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
...    
short[] shortArray = (short[]) rgbBuf.asShortBuffer().array().clone();
```

But I encounter the following problem when running the second line of code shown above:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23923): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
E/AndroidRuntime(23923): at Java.nio.ShortToByteBufferAdapter.protectedArray(ShortToByteBufferAdapter.java:169)
```

Could anyone suggest a means to implement the conversion?

Answer (score 7):

The method do this is a bit odd, actually. You can do it as below; ordering it is important to convert it to a `short` array.

```
short[] shortArray = new short[size/2];
rgbBuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shortArray);
```

Additionally, you may have to use `allocateDirect` instead of `allocate`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why using allocateDirect()? Since I don't find any hints from the android documentation.

Comment: It's a hunch based on [a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24327) that was filed. It may be unrelated, but I figured it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with anything that used `asShortBuffer()`.  Here's a way around it (adapted from [2 bytes to short java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736815/2-bytes-to-short-java)):

```
short[] shortArray = new short[rgbBuf.capacity() / 2]);
for (int i=0; i<shortArray.length; i++)
{   
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bb.put(rgbBuf[2*i]);
    bb.put(rgbBuf[2*i + 1]);
    shortArray[i] = bb.getShort(0);
}
```