# Convert C# method to Java

Tags: c#, java

I am looking to convert the following bit of C# code to Java. I having a hard time coming up with a equivalent.

### Working C# Code:

```
private ushort ConvertBytes(byte a, byte b, bool flip)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[] { a, b };
    if (!flip)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
    }
    ushort num = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
    //this.Weight = num;
    int xy = 0x3720;
    int num2 = 0x3720 - num;
    if (num2 > -1)
    {
        return Convert.ToUInt16(num2);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the Java Code that does not work. The Big challenge is the "BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer,0). How do i get the Java equal of the working C# method.

### Java Code that is Wrong:

```
private short ConvertBytes(byte a, byte b, boolean flip){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[] { a, b };
    if (!flip){
        return  (short) ((a << 8) | (b & 0xFF));
    }
    short num = (short) ((a << 8) | (b & 0xFF));
    //this.Weight = num;
    int num2 = 0x3720 - num;
    if (num2 > -1){
        return (short)num2;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) uses little endian, so the first byte is the LSB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 bytes to short java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736815/2-bytes-to-short-java)

Comment: Noting also that Java doesn't have an unsigned short: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841461/unsigned-short-in-java

Comment: Hmm... Alvin and Chris. I am not very clear on what Little endian and how i can use it to solve my issue.

Comment: `Endianness ` - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private short ConvertBytes(byte a, byte b, boolean flip){

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byteBuffer.put(a);
    byteBuffer.put(b);
    short num = byteBuffer.getShort(0);

    //this.Weight = num;
    int num2 = 0x3720 - num;
    if (num2 > -1){
        return (short)num2;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: u the man! thanks!! this did the trick and now i can sleep without thinking of code

Comment: @codeNinja I would downvote your comment if ever it was possible.

Comment: @Guillaume - its ok! i am sure he is just saying that for `sense of humor`.

Comment: @Guillaume did i offend someone here? I was just joking. @ AppDeveloper I really do appreciate the help. I was truly stuck. Thanks again

Comment: @codeNinja My comment was about your "now I can sleep without thinking of code" :-)

Comment: Can you explain why you used `LITTLE_ENDIAN`?