# Android buffer size and frequency

Tags: java, android, audio, frequency

I generated sine wave and make a sound using Source data line.

The sampling rate is 44100, and block size 441.

If I play 0.1 second, then generate 4410 short sine wave and make a sound like below.

```
ByteBuffer cBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Constants.BLOCK_SIZE);
    for(int i=0; i<SamplesTotal; i++){  
       if(!cBuf.hasRemaining()){
            cBuf.putShort((short) (Short.MAX_VALUE * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * time)));
            time += samplingInterval;
       }else{
            line.write(cBuf.array(), 0, cBuf.position());
            cBuf.clear();
            cBuf.putShort((short) (Short.MAX_VALUE * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * time)));
            time += samplingInterval;
       }
   }
line.write(cBuf.array(), 0, cBuf.position());
```

The problem now, when I read the data from this sound with smart phone, to find frequency used fftpack read 441 short type data and transform. Such as below source.

```
while (started) {
    int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
    toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / (Short.MAX_VALUE);
}
    transformer.ft(toTransform);
    publishProgress(toTransform);
}
```

To find specific frequency 19000 and 20000, I filtered like that and I printed the frequency like below.

```
int temp = 0;
        int temp_idx=0;
        double freq=0;
        int testFreq_19 = 380;
        int testFreq_20 = 400;

        for (int i = 0; i < toTransform[0].length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int downy = (int) (100 - (toTransform[0][i] * 10));
            int upy = 100;
            if(i>testFreq_19-1 && downy<99){
                if(temp<downy){
                    temp=downy;
                    temp_idx=i;
                }
            }
            canvas.drawLine(x/2, downy, x/2, upy, paint);
        }

        if(temp_idx>testFreq_19-10 && temp_idx<testFreq_19+10){
            freq = testFreq_19*(frequency/882);
        }else if(temp_idx>testFreq_20-10 && temp_idx<testFreq_20+10){
            freq = testFreq_20*(frequency/882);
        }else{
            freq= -1;
        }
        Log.d("frequency log", "frequency: " + String.valueOf(freq));
```

The problem is when I generated for 0.1 second, then 10 block(4410) will write.
When I read from the smart phone I thought I will receive 4410 block which means print 19000 10 times with above source.

However, the result is terrible.  Sometimes receive 20 or 30 times even if 5 times I received. Between the data there is blank(no data) I got the example of results like the following:

```
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: 19000.0
frequency: 19000.0
frequency: 19000.0
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: 19000.0
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: -1
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: 20000
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
frequency: -1
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

When you're generating the sound wave, you are writing out the data in 16-bit samples. However, when you're reading the data back in again, you are processing the data one byte at a time (but still dividing the value by `Short.MAX_VALUE`) which doesn't seem right.

What is the audio data format of the `AudioRecord` object - `ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` or `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`? If it's 8-bit then you should surely be dividing by 127 (`Byte.MAX_VALUE`). If it's 16-bit, then you should assumedly be processing two bytes at a time and converting them to a short.

**Update**

If the `buffer` variable is actually a short array rather than a byte array, then your read code is probably fine as it is and you can ignore my comments above. However, I've just noticed something strange in your write code. In this section:

```
   if(!cBuf.hasRemaining()){
        cBuf.putShort((short) (Short.MAX_VALUE * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * time)));
        time += samplingInterval;
   }else{
        line.write(cBuf.array(), 0, cBuf.position());
        cBuf.clear();
        cBuf.putShort((short) (Short.MAX_VALUE * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * time)));
        time += samplingInterval;
   }
```

Assumedly the condition in that `if` should just be `cBuf.hasRemaining()` without the `!` operator. If the buffer has space remaining you want to write to it. If not, you want to flush what has already been accumulated in the buffer and then clear it before trying to write.

However, as soon as you fix that, I expect you'll get a BufferOverflowException. As I mentioned in the comments, you're using a `ByteBuffer` with a size that is an odd number of bytes, but writing out two bytes at a time. Assumedly the declaration should really be:

```
ByteBuffer cBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Constants.BLOCK_SIZE*2);
```

I'm not sure that any of this is the cause of your other problems, but it's worth fixing to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: both i used pcm16 bit. then do i have to change the format from pcm16 to pcm8? dividing by 127???

Comment: how can i process two bytes at a time and converting them to a short. with above source do i have problem???

Comment: You only need to change to pcm8 if you wanted to process one byte at a time. And I said to divide by 127 because that is the max value for a signed byte - you could probably just use Byte.MAX_VALUE. If you're going to use pcm16, have a look at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736815/2-bytes-to-short-java) for how to convert two bytes to a short. You may need to experiment with the byte order if you're unsure whether the data is big endian or little endian.

Comment: Maybe this blog post will help: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/05/the-abcs-of-pcm-uncompressed-digital.html

Comment: thanks, you guys attention. but, i could not understand well. with above source, i used short type which can represent two byte when i write and read. do i need processing to convert two byte??

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted your code. I saw you were using a `ByteBuffer` when you were writing out the code, and assumed the buffer you were reading into with `audioRecord.read` was a byte array too. If `buffer` is actually a short array, then your code should be fine as it is.

Comment: Although looking at your write code, if `BLOCK_SIZE` is really 441, then you're allocating a `ByteBuffer` with an odd number of bytes, but writing data to it with `putShort` (i.e. two bytes at a time), so I'm surprised you don't get a BufferOverflowException when you get to the end of the buffer. There will be space for one byte left in the buffer, but you're trying to write out a short (i.e. two bytes). Or do you never fill up that buffer? What is the value of `SamplesTotal`?

Comment: I've also updated my answer with other problems I've noticed in the code.