# Why is converting two bytes just with shifting is incocrrent?

Tags: java, byte, short

I read [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736815/2-bytes-to-short-java) topic about shifting. I thought that if I have two bytes:

```
byte hi = //...
byte low = //...
```

why can't I just do that

```
short s = (short)((hi << 8) | low)
```

Why is it incorrect? I thought we 8 bits left shift most significant and leave least significant byte as is. And then just bitwise or them.

Comment: you should use ByteBuffer for that like: ByteBuffer.wrap(valBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();

Comment: @FadySaad I'm aware of `ByteBuffer`. I'm interested in understanding bit-shift operations... just that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives a wrong result because bytes are signed and extended to int to do the calculations. So take for example

```
hi = (byte)0x01;
low = (byte)0x80;
```

then you calculate:

```
0x00000100 | 0xffffff80 -> 0xffffff80
```

which is not the desired result.

You could write it like this instead:

```
short s = (short)((hi << 8) | (low & 0xff))
```